# How to use an ip address Directly with Alamofire?

Tags: swift, ip-address, alamofire

I posted a heavy question recently surrounding this topic, but I need to cover the basics first before I can start doing other tasks. I would like to know how to get data from an ip address instead of a standard url that returns JSON data like so:

```
 func simpleGetRequest()
{
    let parameters = ["takepic":"true"]
    Alamofire.request("http://XXX.XXX.X.XX", parameters:parameters).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let status = response.response?.statusCode
        {
            switch(status)
            {
            case 200:
                print("Successfully taken a pic")
            case 500:
                print("Failed to connect")
            default:
                print("Error with everything")
            }
        }

        if let result = response.result.value
        {
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

I've heard some things about IPv6 and IPv4, but am not sure as to what they mean. I'll continue to do more research, however I can't find a single source that shows how to communicate with non-local web servers.

Comment: Well technically a "standard URL" is just a pretty name for an underlying IP address. For example http://17.172.224.47 is http://apple.com. Therefore I'm not sure the "non-locality" is your issue here.

Comment: Yeah I agree, the non-locality is my issue at hand here